# Microsoft AzureAI ChatBot

Tags: artificial-intelligence, azure-ai

Looking to use the chatbot and was wondering if there is a way to make an API based on a specific question? I have looked through the Azure documentation and can only find documentation about importing data and not triggering a push of data.